# Build an object after user registers in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

So i'm having this issue trying to figure out how to use the build method in rails to create an object once a user completely registers and still have that object connected to the users id. I'm using devise for authentication and the model that needs to be created is called "app".

This is the create method for "app".

```
 def create
  @app = App.new(app_params)
  @app.id = current_user.id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @app.save
        format.html { redirect_to @app, notice: 'Application successfully created.'}
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
      end
    end
  end
```

Im getting this error: 
Couldn't find App with id=1

from my multi step form controller:

```
def show
       @user = User.find(current_user)
          case step
        when :school, :grades, :extra_activity, :paragraph, :submit
        @app = App.find(current_user)
      end
        render_wizard
      end
```

Comment: What's the association between the `App` and `User` models?

Comment: And what's the question?  Does you code not work? what are the error messages, the log file?

Comment: @bjelli Im getting this error: Couldn't find App with id=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an `after_create` callback in the User model. It makes no sense to mess with the AppController because no forms have been filled up for the app and you have no app_params.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :build_initial_app

  protected

  def build_initial_app
    self.create_app
  end
end
```

You can read more about this at the Rails Guides page for [ActiveRecord Callbacks](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html).

Comment: I have the correct association between my App model and User model. I need rails to build the actual "App" form after a user registers so that a user can edit their form without having to actually create one them selves.

Comment: Wouldn't I need a method in the User model (which is using devise) that builds the app form after the user registers? It doesn't seem to right for it to go in the apps controller.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "builds the app form". Forms reside in views, and anything that has to do with views should be kept as separate from models as possible. Models don't build forms, views do. Don't you already have a form to create the first app in your view?

Comment: When a user is created, an app also needs to be created. When I currently go into rails console and type App.all it shows an empty array. I need it so when a user registers, an app is also created and given the user_id in the database.

Comment: OK, then you need an `after_create` callback in the User model. You shouldn't be messing with the AppController because you got no app_params to begin with. If what I said makes sense, I can update my answer.

Comment: makes complete sense! thats exactly what im looking for, mind sharing a little tutorial how I would implement this in my user model?

Comment: Im getting undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass

Comment: That means you don't have an association called `apps` for your users.

Comment: schema: create_table "apps", force: true do |t|
t.integer  "user_id"

Comment: User has_one :app   App belongs_to :user

Comment: Updated. That's why that information was important to begin with. ;-)

Comment: Not getting an error this time, but the app is still not being created :(

Comment: Try `create_app` instead of `build_app`.

Comment: Works! thanks! one last question. Is there any way to set the app id in that after create call back? something like this? @app.id = current_user.id

Comment: Nice, I'm glad to know that. And no, you should NEVER do that. ActiveRecord sets the primary key for you. If you need to access the app that was created, just use user.app.

Comment: makes sense, regardless the app id is going to be the same as user id since they are being created together. thanks once again, you'v been a great help.

Comment: That's cool. Feel free to upvote my answer if you liked it too. :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem line in your code is here:

```
@app.id = current_user.id
```

Setting an ActiveRecord object's `id` is a no-no. Think of the `id` attribute like you would a pointer in C. The system creates it for you, and you can use it to refer to a unique model object.

What you probably want is something along the lines of:

```
@app.user_id = current_user.id
```

Or, even better:

```
@app.user = current_user
```

To do that, you need to set up an association between your App model and your User model. There's a good tutorial on that [here.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)